# Docker mysql container mysteriously fills drive

Tags: mysql, linux, docker

I am using docker (20.10.1, build 831ebea) with the official latest mysql container (8.0.22) on an Ubuntu host (20.04.1). When running a large query, the container uses all available free space on my disk (588G). During execution, however, I cannot locate the files that are consuming the drive.

I started the container as follows:

```sh
docker run --name mysql-1                                \
    -v /mnt/data/mysql-data/config/:/etc/mysql/conf.d    \
    -v /mnt/data/mysql-data/data/:/var/lib/mysql         \
    -v /mnt/data/mysql-data/tmp/:/tmp                    \
    -p 127.0.0.1:3307:3306 -d mysql
```

In this case, `/mnt/data/` is a 2TB drive using EXT4 and has 588G free space before running any queries. Everything works until I start running the large query. When the query is running, space on the disk quickly falls (times are on the left)...

```sh
15:33 $ df -h | grep data
/dev/nvme0n1p1                    1.8T  1.3T  580G  69% /mnt/data

15:37 $ df -h | grep data
/dev/nvme0n1p1                    1.8T  1.3T  555G  70% /mnt/data
```

Eventually, the entire drive is consumed and the query ends with `ERROR 3 (HY000) at line 14: Error writing file '/tmp/MYfd=41' (OS errno 28 - No space left on device)`. Once the query fails, all the disk space returns.

The mystery is that while `df` reports the available space filling up, `du -h` doesn't and offers no clues as to what files are taking up space...

```sh
15:32 data$ sudo du -s .
1286106888      .

15:33 data$ sudo du -s .
1286106888      .

15:37 data$ sudo du -s .
1286106888      .
```

- One might think `/mnt/data/mysql-data/tmp/` is the culprit, but `ls -a` reports the directory is empty.
- Similarly, `du -s /var/lib/docker/containers/` reports no changes in file/directory sizes while the query runs.
- Running these commands from within the container (`docker exec -it mysql-1 /bin/bash`) produces the same pattern...

  - `df -h` shows available space dropping during the query
  - `du -s /` shows no changes in sizes
  - `ls -a /tmp/` doesn't show any files

I am struggling to troubleshoot the mysql query because I can't figure out what's taking up the 588G of disk space during execution.

Any ideas why this happens?

EDIT: Information about the database...

- The query is using `JSON_TABLE` to expand a JSON column into one row per key-value pair. The original table is a 125G compressed MyISAM table (the uncompressed data are about 240G) with the following schema...

```sql
CREATE TABLE `raw_visits` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `place_id` char(35) NOT NULL,
  `dt` date NOT NULL,
  `visitor_cbgs` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_place_date` (`place_id`,`dt`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

- Then, I'm trying to build a new table that split the JSON column into several rows...

```sql
-- new table for one row per key-value pair in visitor_cbgs
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cbg_visitors (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    place_id CHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    dt DATE NOT NULL,
    cbg CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    visitors MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY idx_place_date_cbg (place_id, dt, cbg)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT IGNORE INTO cbg_visitors

    (place_id, dt, cbg, visitors)

    SELECT  m.place_id,
            m.dt,
            JSON_UNQUOTE(
            JSON_EXTRACT(
                JSON_KEYS(m.visitor_cbgs),
                CONCAT('$[',
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.place_id, dt) - 1,
                    ']'
                )
            )) AS cbg,
            visitors

    FROM raw_visits m

    JOIN JSON_TABLE(
        m.visitor_cbgs, '$.*' COLUMNS (visitors INT PATH '$')
    ) j

    WHERE m.visitor_cbgs IS NOT NULL;
```

- This `INSERT ... SELECT` for building the new table is what causes the disk space issue.
- `SELECT VERSION();` --> 8.0.22
- `EXPLAIN` on the `SELECT` portion of the `INSERT` statement shows...

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | m | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 142371487 | 90.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | j | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2 | 100.00 | Table function: json_table; Using temporary |

Comment: What query are you running ? How big  database is ?

Comment: show your query, and output of `select version();`, `explain select rest-of-your-large-query`, and `show create table ...` for all tables used in the query?

Comment: I updated the question with more details about the schema and query.

Comment: The most common culprit in Linux-land for situations such as this (disk filling up, reported file sizes not increasing) are files that were deleted while being written to.  Have a look at `lsof | grep -i deleted` ... if there is output for files on the filesystem you're concerned about, you have identified where the space is going.

Comment: @tink, That's exactly what's happening. I see two temp files (e.g. `/tmp/#4587526` is the container path). Both are "deleted" but grow in size throughout the query until exhausting the available space. So, is there a fix?

Comment: Hard to say; I'm not a MySQL guru, but I **guess** that it creates a temporary table for the `JOIN` (which it deletes so people don't tamper with it as it goes) ... it could be a bug in the version of MySQL in your packaged docker; it could just be that the result set **really is** that huge - in which case you may have to re-write that query to achieve its results in a less expensive manner.